# Prism Regions error Prism.Regions.IActiveRegionHelper

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, region

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.1874 and Prism 8.0.0.1909

I'm trying to use Regions and the region doesn't appear. In the callback for navigating to region I'm getting the following error

```
Prism.Ioc.ContainerResolutionException
An unexpected error occured while resolving Prism.Regions.IActiveRegionHelper
```

The application doesn't crash. The region just doesn't appear where is suppose to (if I understood the concept of regions correctly) I made a simple example with the code that I'm using. The example can be found in the following GitHub repository

https://github.com/gnout/PrismRegion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue with Prism Unity container.

As provided by Dan [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2227#issuecomment-733094666)  you can switch to Prism DryLoc while waiting for a fix on the Unity side.

Comment: An issue with Prism's wrapper for the Unity container, to be precise, Unity itself is innocent here and working fine.

Comment: Yep, as we are in the prism context I though it would be obvious, but you are right to specify it